# What are the recommendations for building OpenCV 3.0 in presense of respectable number of 3d party components?

Tags: opencv, opencl, tbb, intel-ipp

When I desided to build opencv library I have found out that there are number of compiler options available that does nearly the same - speed up algorithms. For example: TBB, IPP, CUDA, pthreads, Eigen2/Eigen3, OpenCL and others. Are there any benchmarks or known recommendations of what options are better than others and what caveats should be known?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your system needs.
CUDA for example is relevant only if you have NVIDIA grpahic card, IPP only if you have the correct intel processor.